# DRF annotated queryset filtering with django-filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-annotate

can anyone help with filtering in DRF.
I have some products models, say `Product` and manager `ProductManager`:

```
class ProductItem(Model):
    price = DecimalField()

class Product(Model):
    items = ManyToManyField(ProductItem)
    priceman = ProductManager()

class ProductManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset().annotate(total_price=Sum('items__price'))
    return qs
```

Here if filter class:

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = {
            'total_price': ['lt', 'gt'],
        }
```

Here is view:

```
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.priceman.all()
    filterset_class = ProductFilter
```

and I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'Meta.fields' contains fields that are not defined on this FilterSet: total_price
```

How should I configure the filter class to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

I found answer, this can be done by changing filter class like this:

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    min_price = NumberFilter(field_name="total_price", lookup_expr='gt')
    max_price = NumberFilter(field_name="total_price", lookup_expr='lt')
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['min_price', 'max_price']
```